# Find whether the "call" action happened after the "raise" in Poker

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, parsing

This input of this function is a list of Poker actions on the flop (assume this is the only betting street). Howewer, the function does erronenessly output `no_calls_other_than_original_bettor = True` for this example. However, this can't be true, since Robert2 called Brittney3's bet.

("called" means that his bet is equal to previous maximum bet; "raise" means that the bet is larger than the previous bet.)

```
def analyse_poker_actions(actions):
    players = set()
    bettor = None
    raiser = None
    call_players = []
    raise_players = []
    betting_street = None
    raise_players_excluding_bettor = []
    fold_actions = []
    bettor_actions = []
    for action in actions:
        players.add(action['player'])
        if action['action'] == 'bets':
            bettor = action['player']
            if betting_street is None:
                betting_street = action['street']
        if action['player'] == bettor:
            bettor_actions.append(action['action'])
        if action['action'] == 'calls':
            call_players.append(action['player'])
        if action['action'] == 'raises':
            raise_players.append(action['player'])
            if action['player'] != bettor:
                raise_players_excluding_bettor.append(action['player'])
                if raiser is None:
                    raiser = action['player']

        if action['action'] == 'folds':
            fold_actions.append(action['player'])

    player_bet_and_folded = bettor in fold_actions

    no_calls_other_than_original_bettor = all(player != bettor and player != raiser for player in call_players)

    cold4bet = len(set(raise_players_excluding_bettor)) > 1

    if 'raises' in bettor_actions and 'folds' in bettor_actions:
        bettor_reraised = bettor_actions.index('raises') < bettor_actions.index('folds')
    else:
        bettor_reraised = False
    return betting_street, player_bet_and_folded,no_calls_other_than_original_bettor,cold4bet, bettor_reraised, len(players),len(raise_players_excluding_bettor)
```

The function does output `('FLOP', True, True, False, False, 6, 1)`
instead of `('FLOP', True, False, False, False, 6, 1)` - for this test

```
test1= [{'street': 'FLOP', 'player': 'John4', 'position': 4, 'action': 'checks'},
 {'street': 'FLOP', 'player': 'Jane0', 'position': 0, 'action': 'checks'}, 
{'street': 'FLOP', 'player': 'Brittney2', 'position': 2, 'action': 'bets', 'amount': 18.0},
 {'street': 'FLOP', 'player': 'Robert3', 'position': 3, 'action': 'calls', 'amount': 18.0},
 {'street': 'FLOP', 'player': 'John4', 'position': 4, 'action': 'raises', 'amount': 94.0},
 {'street': 'FLOP', 'player': 'Jane0', 'position': 0, 'action': 'folds'}, 
 {'street': 'FLOP', 'player': 'Brittney2', 'position': 2, 'action': 'folds'}, 
{'street': 'FLOP', 'player': 'Robert3', 'position': 3, 'action': 'folds'}]
```